# qt holding mouse button and timer cpp

Tags: c++, qt, timer, qmouseevent

I dont konw how to connect timers timeout and mouseevent class. I need to draw a new particle in "waterfield" (qwidget) when mouse button is pressed every 200 ms. When i release the button painter should not draw more.
I got this in my constructor:

```
timertap.setInterval(200);
timertap.start();
connect(&timertap,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(taptap()));
setMouseTracking(true);
```

In my class there are slot *taptap()* and bool *tapenable*.

This is code which is not working:

```
void waterfield::taptap()
{
    QMouseEvent *e;
    if(tapenable && e->button()==Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        particle p;
        int x=e->pos().x();
        int y=e->pos().y();
        p.position.y=y;
        p.position.x=x;
        zbiorczastek.push_back(p);
        painter.drawEllipse(x,y,particlesize,particlesize);
    }
}

void waterfield::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    tapenable=true;
}

void waterfield::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    tapenable=true;
}
```

After i click program crashs. I think its a good idea to do it this way. Timer is set to 200ms, so every 200ms signal timeout is set and slot taptap recive it and check if tapenable is set by mousepressevent or reset by mousereleaseevent.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare a pointer in **waterfield::taptap()**:

```
QMouseEvent *e;
```

without initializing it, so the program crashes as using an unitialized pointer is undefined behaviour.

Apart from this, you're using **QMouseEvent** the wrong way. You seem to think that this object represents some global mouse state that is available through any object of type QMouseEvent. This is not true. A QMouseEvent object that actually represents the current mouse state is caught by slots that take **QMouseEvent *e** as an argument, such as **mousePressEvent()**.

You need to call the **taptap()** method from **mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)**, and pass **mousePressEvent**'s **QMouseEvent *e** argument to the **taptap()** function. You also should start the timer in the **mousePressEvent()** slot and stop it inside the **mouseReleaseEvent()**.

Comment: but how to connect timerout signal which has no arguments with taptap slot which now has qmouseevent * as an argument?

Comment: I guess the easiest solution would be using QCursor::pos() rather than QMouseEvent if all you need from the latter is coordinates. QCursor::pos() is a static function, so you can call it from whichever place you like and don't have to worry about passing objects.

Answer (score 1):

> After i click program crashs.

You need to learn to debug your code instead of asking others to do it for you.

You should not be drawing in a slot connected to a timer; you should do it in the [`paintEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#paintEvent) function. In the timer slot, you simply add the particle and call `update()`. Then you start the timer in `mousePressEvent` and stop it in `mouseReleaseEvent`. You also don't need `setMouseTracking`, because this is done automatically while you keep the mouse button pressed.

Comment: I guess you missed the first line of my answer.

Comment: Deleting those lines doesnt change anything. I have got segmentation fault in "Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline QPoint QPointF::toPoint() const
{
    return QPoint(qRound(xp), qRound(yp));
}"